# Django CSRF check failing in JavaScript post request like a form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I am using the answer here ([JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)) to do post in my javascript at the brower. But Django CSRF checking failed because there is {% csrf_token %} in the form in the template. How to do it？ Should I add the following piece of codes?

```
var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", 'csrfmiddlewaretoken');
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", '{{ csrf_token }}');
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
```

**Any hints, suggestions and comments welcomed.** Thanks

Comment: Is it that you are creating a complete form in javascript and appending it to your template somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

If you are submitting form using ajax you also have to submit csrf token value.
For an example.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data:{
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
    },
    success: function(response){
    }
});
```

or you can send serialize form in ajax data as

```js
data: $("#form").serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the getCookie() function from https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/static/js/csrf.js and post() function from [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit).

Final codes:

```
// https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/static/js/csrf.js
function getCookie(name) {
    console.log('getCookie');
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
    console.log('cookie:' + cookieValue);
    return cookieValue;
}
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit
function post(path, params, method) {
        method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);
        for(var key in params) {
                if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
                        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                }
        }
        var hiddenField1 = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField1.setAttribute("name", 'csrfmiddlewaretoken');
        hiddenField1.setAttribute("value", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        form.appendChild(hiddenField1);

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
}
```

**Any comments welcomed.**

Comment: You are the first person i see using 8 space indention

Comment: @Endless It is wired. I have no idea why 8. I will figure out why.

Comment: @Endless Thanks. I did something wrong when copy and paste. and on my new VM, I did not set .vimrc